# Where does this space come from?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to build my website and I'm now trying to get many form inputs on one line. To do this I override the input padding using

```
.padding-one {
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

and the html of the right side of the form should contain two small icons for which I reserve space like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 padding-one">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 padding-one">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 padding-one">
            icon1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 padding-one">
            icon2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This however, results in the following:

[image]

The two question marks already indicate my surprise:

1. Why does the first text ("icon1") disappear partly under the previous input?
2. Where does the space between "icon1" and "icon2" come from?

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Comment: for question 2 the space between `icon1` and `icon2` is due to the `col-xs-6` width declared in `bootstrap.min.css` file

Comment: Under input because normally .row have margin-left  to be -15px so it go under.  And while the space may be you are styling after bootstrap include so it have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the first text ("icon1") disappear partly under the previous input?

If you go through bootstrap's CSS you will see that every col-* has a `padding`. Your CSS definition overrides the default padding causing the grid to not work properly.

Instead of overriding the padding look at [Forms Docs @ Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). There's a special implementation of the framework for inline forms.

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

> Where does the space between "icon1" and "icon2" come from?

First you have `.col-sm-1` which lets say is `200px` inside you have 2x .`col-x-6` which will divide those `200px` (*example*) and every `div` will have the width of `100px`. If the texts "icon1" & "icon2" take `50px` of each `div` then that's why you have space between "icon1" & "icon2". Even though you have overrided the  default `padding`.

Here's an example fiddle using `form.form-inline`: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xsb62L3s/)

If the 8 inputs can't fit in the viewport in one line it will split them on 2 lines with 4 inputs. (resize the HTML output pane to see how it works).

This is for better user experience.

But if you **explicitly** want them to be all horizontally aligned then you can do something like this. (I don't recommend that because the inputs on smaller screens would be hard to use.)

Here's the demo for this approach: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xsb62L3s/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications and also for your suggestion to solve it with the inline form. The thing is that I'm trying to fit all my inputs (8!!) on one line, and when I try to do that using an inline form, the inputs spread over two lines. Would you know if there is any trick to force all form inputs in an inline form to fit on one line?

Comment: You want those inputs (8) to be on one line for all screen sizes? Or when it's smaller to be 2 lines with 4 inputs?

Comment: At least on one line on large screens. On smaller ones they could indeed fit on two. But most important is large screens for this website.

Comment: See my updated answer. I **do** recommend the first approach, because it provides better user experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the reasons to go for the first approach, but having everything on one line is extremely important for us. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are overriding the bootstrap padding for columns. The default bootstrap padding is required because it adds space between the columns.

This style:

```
.padding-one {
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

Overrides:

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3,    .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Alright, so would you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I dunno dude. It's a complicated situation. Maybe remove the `.padding-one` ?

Answer (score -1):

Space is coming due to .col-xs-6 class by default it has width of 50%. you over-ride it with your custom css So that you can overcome space issue.

Comment: But this will break `.col-xs-6` all over his application, causing the Bootstrap framework's grid to malfunction, making it useless. *If someone has to override the default CSS for the grid, he is probably doing something wrong.*

Comment: i said to override with custom css .. He can go like .row  > .col-xs-6 .custom-class ..Dont down vote blindly with out knowing properly.

Comment: But why do I have to override something, when there's a cleaner and better approach?

Comment: If he is want to have structure which is not actual then he need to override. Everythng depends on requirement.If my approach doesn't works then me know.  and also Let me know how can you overcome the issue with cleaner..??

Comment: With out using col-xs-6 class .you defined custom-col class  and also you restructured the whole html according to it.. But i didnt went through that scenarios. I just went through the give code and given the solution based on his code. i.e  I mentioned to define the custom class along with  col-xs-6  and override the properties which he need . Independently i wont affect  col-xs-6 class.

Comment: Yes,  that's the second suggestion. I said it's highly not recommended. I provided a cleaner and better apprpach.